# store a database record to a list

Tags: java, database, jsp, resultset

How can I put database record into a ArrayList? I want to view it in a jsp files. But, the value of all object in ArrayList is same as the last record in database I selected.

I have these code in my project:

**IPBean.java**

```
public class IPBean {
    private String ip;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private int maxRetry;    

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }    
    protected void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }    
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }    
    protected void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }    
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }    
    protected void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }    
    public int getMaxRetry() {
        return maxRetry;
    }    
    protected void setMaxRetry(int maxRetry) {
        this.maxRetry = maxRetry;
    }    
}
```

**IPBeanMapper.java**

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IPBeanMapper {
    public ArrayList<IPBean> getIPList() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<IPBean> ipList = new ArrayList<IPBean>();
        Connection conn = null;
        conn = ConnectionTools.getConnection();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM LIST_IPM";
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        IPBean ipBean = new IPBean();

        while (rs.next()){

            ipBean.setIp(rs.getString("IP"));
            ipBean.setMaxRetry(rs.getInt("NUM_OF_RETRY"));
            ipBean.setPassword(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
            ipBean.setUserName(rs.getString("USERNAME"));

            ipList.add(ipBean);

        }
        ConnectionTools.attemptClose(rs);
        ConnectionTools.attemptClose(statement);
        ConnectionTools.attemptClose(conn);
        System.out.print(ipList.size());
        return ipList;
    }
}
```

**View.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" import="DSIP.*" import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>DSIP.Insert</title>
</head>

<body>
<jsp:useBean id="ipList" scope="application" class="IPBeanMapper"/>
<jsp:useBean id="bean" scope="application" class="IPBean"/>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="viewServlet">
    <table width="" border="">
        <tr bgcolor="#0099FF">
            <td width="90"><div align="center">ip</div></td>
            <td width="90"><div align="center">username</div></td>
            <td width="90"><div align="center">password</div></td>
            <td width="90"><div align="center">maxRetry</div></td>
        </tr>
        <%
            ArrayList<IPBean> list;
            list = ipList.getIPList();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                bean = list.get(i);
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="ip"        type="text" size="15" value="<%=list.getIp()%>"></td>
            <td><input name="userName"  type="text" size="15" value="<%=bean.getUserName()%>"></td>
            <td><input name="password"  type="text" size="15" value="<%=bean.getPassword()%>"></td>
            <td><input name="maxRetry"  type="text" size="15" value="<%=bean.getMaxRetry()%>"></td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result in my browser shows that the first and second record is indentic when in fact not the same. So, please somebody help me to show the real records from database.

to see my result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lIM9.png

Thank you very much for helping me.

Best Regards,

Faizal Rizky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
   IPBean ipBean = new IPBean(); 

    while (rs.next()){
```

to

```
 while (rs.next()){

 IPBean ipBean = new IPBean();
```

This will create new instance per row, which is required, otherwise it will keep overriding data in a single instance

Answer (score 2):

you need to put this `IPBean ipBean = new IPBean();` inside while loop

so your code will become -

**IPBeanMapper.java**

```
while (rs.next()){ 
IPBean ipBean = new IPBean();   
.
.
```

The problem the same object reference is getting added in the list. So all initial entries are same as ur last record.

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont have to put the whole

```
ipBean bean = new IPBean();
```

into the loop. That would be a bad practice. Just declare

ipBean ipBean;

```
while(rs.next()){
      bean = new ipBean();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    IPBean ipBean = new IPBean();

    while (rs.next()){

        ipBean.setIp(rs.getString("IP"));
```

You need to make a new instance for every row. Move the `new IPBean` inside of the loop. Otherwise, you end up with the same instance multiple times in the list, with the values you set in the last iteration.