# Sending a great number data to servlet

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring, servlets

My web app is about online quiz. So having a multiple number of question is common. I made a form for the questionnaire/quiz which consist of **50 items**. But I don't know what approach should I do to send it the servlet.

**Note:** I'm using Spring

The approach I thought is:

1. Set all the values in a `hidden` as an array ( but I don't know if this is possible )
2. Send it like always, by name ( but this will load the 50 parameters to the controller )

If there is another approach than this to, kindly explain it to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a bean?, take a look at spring form (assuming you're using spring MVC)

Comment: @RC. If I use a bean. that would make the bean 50 properties?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511647/spring-binding-values-in-a-map on how to use a map with spring form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible solutions which come to my mind

1 : hidden fields ( yeah its possible by the way ) ==> no encouraged though

set all the values in your view page in hidden text fields

and keep passing these values from one page to another

2 : binding the values to the session

set all the values in some collection object and pass the collection object binding it to the session

3 : Bean
create a user defined bean covering all the fields you want to pass

store the values in the bean object

and only pass the bean reference from page to page

since you are not passing the complete object but only the reference , works better performance wise

Comment: I like the bean. Is it the spring form? But that will make the bean have 50 attributes in case that I need 50 questions? Can I somehow put it in a List? but I don't know if its possible

Comment: you can put a single arraylist in the bean haveing 50 question entry

Comment: But how will I represent in the form? if it is from arraylist? `<form:input path="">`? I don't know how if it is in a collection

Comment: refer [THIS LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258745/store-a-database-record-to-a-list)

Comment: Sir can I not use scriplet?